# How to make the background image change without a button with HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the background image change without a button, with any click in the back but its not working.
I tried to set the default background image defined in the CSS:

```css
background-image: url('https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1920/1080/63/70/jE2ups.jpg');
```

And use this JavaScript, but once the imagen change I cant go back to the old one.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hxst1/hxst1.github.io/main/img/p2.jpg')";
}
```

Also tried `$document` on click but im new at this and its not working either.

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the background image?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle between 2 images it can easily be done by toggling a class on the body

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle("bgr");
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1920/1080/63/70/jE2ups.jpg');
}
.bgr {
  background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hxst1/hxst1.github.io/main/img/p2.jpg') !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Spectric commented you can toggle background image:

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function (){
    document.body.classList.toggle('body_change');
})
```

```css
.body_change {
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300');
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200');
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function myBackground(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hxst1/hxst1.github.io/main/img/p2.jpg')";
})
```

Comment: Its still the same, if you click once, you cant go back to the "default" image

Answer (score 0):

if you want to automatic change every 1,2,3 or any seconds, you can try this way.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function myBackground(){
    changeBackground();
})

let images = [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485322551133-3a4c27a9d925?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507842217343-583bb7270b66?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=853&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600498148212-62bd3542ed63?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611091428036-e0211d8016f0?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=745&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600431521340-491eca880813?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80'
];

let index = 0;
function changeBackground(){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+images[index]+"')";
  index = (index < images.length-1) ? (index+1) : 0;
}


// change backgroubd every 3 seconds
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
  changeBackground()
}, 3000); // 1000 = 1 second

// function to stop interval 
// clearInterval(interval)
```

```html
<h3>
change background
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to toggle an image so you set the background image in css then switched it in javascript but forgot to write in the javascript the conditional statements (if/else). Basically if background is the first picture then change it to the second picture else change to first picture. Your code only says to change it to second picture.

```
function background(){
var body = document.body;
if(body.style.backgroundImage = "url('pic1')"){
body.style.backgroundImage = "url('pic2')";
} else {
body.style.backgroundImage = "url('pic1')";
}
}
```